# Probability of putting p balls in boxes

Tags: probability

There are "n" boxes. Balls are placed randomly in the boxes one at a time until either box receives two balls. What is the probability of exactly putting p balls in boxes?

I don't understand why the denominator in probability is $n^p$. shouldn't it be all possibilities ($1$ ball, $2$ balls, ..., $(n + 1)$ balls)?

Comment: The rules are not clear here.  How many balls are there?  What does "either box" mean in the case when $n\neq 2$?  What is the meaning of the $2$ ball limit:  that is, if I try to throw a ball into a box that already has $2$ balls in it, does the ball go into a different box or does something else happen?   Perhaps you can illustrate the possible outcomes for small $n$ (like $n=1$ or $2$).

Comment: but the question does not detail anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take an easy example.

Imagine you have **2** boxes.

> What is the probability of having exactly *k* balls among the **2**
>   boxes ?

Observe first that having $k = 0$ is impossible. Neither do $k = 1$.

However, having $k = 2$ is possible, it is the case when you put the two balls in one box. The probability of it is composed of randomly choosing two boxes : 1/2*1/2.

The true probability is $1/2 = (1/2 * 1/2) * 2$.  Inside the parenthesis the $1/n^p$ !!! It corresponds to the probability of choosing the two boxes where one put the balls.

What about $k =3$ ? You'll observe it is putting 1 ball in whichever box, and 2 in the other one : again we need to choose 3 times boxes (with repetition) where to put the balls: $1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2$.

In other words : whatsoever number of balls you choose (reasonably enough balls. When p < 2, the probability is equal to 0 and when p > n+1, the probability is also obviously equal to 0), you will at some point chose $p$ box among $n$ : $1/n^p$.

**Then of course you multiply this number by something else to get the true probability.** But the point the question is not to get the true probability.

Answer (score 2):

Each of $p$ balls, has $n$ places it can go. So there are $n^p$ arrangements with repetitions allowed. Also balls need to be distinguishable.